# Con que valores se inicializan los elementos de un array tipo char

Tags: c

Tengo el siguiente programa:

```
int main(){
    char condominio[20][20];


    return 0;
}
```

¿que valores contendria cada elemento de condominio? ¿Algún carácter especial? ya que al imprimir no veo nada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ¿que valores contendria cada elemento de condominio?

El contenido será al azar o indeterminado, `condominio` ocupará 20 x 20 bytes (asumiendo que `char` ocupa un byte) los cuales no estarán inicializados.

Es decir: se ocuparán 400 bytes de memoria, tuviera lo que tuviera la memoria antes de ser solicitada por `condominio` y esa memoria podría tener cualquier valor dependiendo de cómo maneje la memoria tu sistema operativo.

Por ejemplo, hay sistemas operativos que cuando liberan memoria no borran el contenido de la misma si no que la marcan como disponible, por ejemplo podría pasar<sup>1</sup> que...

```
char *frase = malloc(16);
memcpy(frase, "Mi mama me mima", 16);
free(frase);
char *otra_frase = malloc(16);
```

... la variable `otra_frase` apuntase a una memoria que contuviese `"Mi mama me mima"` pese a que dicha información se habría borrado con la instrucción `free(frase)`.

Sabiendo esto, la variable `condominio` sin inicializar sus valores podría contener cualquier residuo de memoria de ejecuciones paralelas o anteriores.

> ¿Algún carácter especial? ya que al imprimir no veo nada.

Apuesto a que has impreso así:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 20; ++x)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 20; ++y)
        printf("%c ", condominio[x][y]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Y no has visto absolutamente nada... intenta cambiar imprimir un caracter (`"%c "`) por imprimir un número (`"%d "`):

```
for (int x = 0; x < 20; ++x)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 20; ++y)
        printf("%d ", condominio[x][y]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Con ese cambio, en mi caso [la ejecución ha mostrado](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/9V4A0aNUOcFOx6Mj)<sup>2</sup>:

> ```
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -64 -1 -97 -1 -118 127 0 0 48 -6 -97 -1 
> -118 127 0 0 77 3 64 0 0 0 0 0 80 58 33 -1 -118 127 0 0 
> -72 2 64 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 20 8 0 0 
> 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 32 38 -96 -1 -118 127 0 0 
> -64 101 106 48 -2 127 0 0 46 78 61 -10 0 0 0 0 -64 -1 -97 -1 
> -118 127 0 0 -32 101 106 48 -2 127 0 0 -56 34 -96 -1 -118 127 0 0 
> -29 -124 126 -1 -118 127 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -64 -1 -97 -1 
> -118 127 0 0 1 0 0 0 -118 127 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
> 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -56 34 -96 -1 -118 127 0 0 0 0 0 0 
> 0 0 0 0 80 -11 -97 -1 -118 127 0 0 -104 102 106 48 -2 127 0 0 
> -24 -75 55 -1 -118 127 0 0 0 -118 92 -1 -118 127 0 0 0 40 0 0 
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 32 38 -96 -1 -118 127 0 0 
> -32 -117 125 -1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 80 -11 -97 -1 
> -118 127 0 0 77 3 64 0 0 0 0 0 0 122 55 -1 -118 127 0 0 
> 64 50 42 -1 -118 127 0 0 -32 119 92 -1 -118 127 0 0 125 48 44 0 
> 0 0 0 0 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -65 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
> -82 101 106 48 -2 127 0 0 -81 101 106 48 -2 127 0 0 -104 46 33 -1 
> -118 127 0 0 33 4 64 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
> 93 6 64 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6 64 0 
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 112 4 64 0 0 0 0 0
> ```

El motivo por el que no se imprime nada son todos esos ceros que le dicen a la salida estándar que se han acabado los caracteres a imprimir (el cero (`0`) indica el final de cadena). Si casualmente `condiminio[0][0]` hubiera tenido un caracter imprimible éste se habría mostrado junto a todos los caracteres posteriores imprimibles hasta encontrar otro cero.

Si cambias el código para imprimir cadenas en lugar de caracteres:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 20; ++x)
    printf("%s\n", condominio[x]);
```

Se imprimirá cada `condominio[x]` que empiece con un caracter imprimible; en mi caso he visto el siguiente disparate:

> ```
> 4
> �@
>
> `d.P�a: 4
> �]4
> 4
>
>
> 襦]4
>
> �]
> 4
> @"�]4
>
> Nd.P�a: 4
> �@
> ```

Ten en cuenta que usar el valor de variables no incializadas es comportamiento no definido, así que podría pasar cualquier cosa inesperada... como por ejemplo que no se muestre nada.

---

<sup>1</sup>También podría no pasar, es dependiente de cómo maneje el sistema operativo la memoria.

<sup>2</sup>El contenido puede variar en cada ejecución.

Answer (score 0):

```
char condominio[20][20];
```

Esa línea está creando una variable que es capaz de almacenar 20 cadenas de caracteres, cada una de las cuales podrá almacenar hasta 20 caracteres (contando el posible carácter nulo de final de cadena).

¿Qué valor contiene cada cadena? Su valor inicial es el que tuviesen las posiciones de memoria en las que se ubica la variable. En C no hay constructores ni inicializadores por defecto. Si quieres que una posición de memoria tenga un valor inicial por defecto tendrás que programarlo explícitamente:

```
int array[10]; // Cada posición del array tendrá un valor aleatorio (basura)

int array[10] = {2}; // Cada valor del array se inicializa con valor 2

int array[10] = { 1,2,3 }; // Las tres primeras posiciones se incializan con la secuencia 1,2,3 y el resto con 0

int array[10] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}; // Se le asigna un valor específico a cada elemento del array

static int array[10]; // Al ser un elemento estático se inicializa, por defecto, a 0.
```

Por supuesto este tipo de incializaciones únicamente sirven para valores conocidos en tiempo de compilación. Para valores variables puedes iterar sobre el array con un bucle, por ejemplo.

En cuanto a lo que comentas de imprimir... no indicas cómo estás sacando  por pantalla las variables así que esa parte se queda pendiente de que edites la pregunta. Eso sí, ten en cuenta que no todos valores del rango `char` se corresponden con caracteres imprimibles. Imprimir uno de estos caracteres puede tener resultados de lo más variopintos (saltos de línea, retornos de carro, símbolos extraños, ...)

Comment: Realmente jamas lo vi como un array de 20 cadenas, mi objetivo era generar un mapa de 20 x 20 donde cada posición de ese mapa (x,y) contenga un carácter para señalar su estado.

Comment: @CristoferFuentes Es otra opción. Nadie te obliga a usar los elementos como cadenas. Es simplemente que en C char[X] es una estructura que habitualmente se usa para cadenas... pero no hay limitaciones para usarla como caracteres independientes.

Answer (score 0):

Tu pregunta se basa en un array bidimensional tipo char, puedes inicializarlo de esta forma:

```
int main(){

    char *condominio[20][20] = {{"a", "b"},  {"c", "d"}};

    return 0;
}
```

Para imprimir su contenido puedes realizar:

```
 int main(){

  char *condominio[20][20] ={{"a", "b"},  {"c", "d"}};

  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
  {
       for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++) 
       {
         printf("%s", condominio[i][j]);
       }
    printf("\n");
  } 
  return 0;

}
```

obteniendo como salida algo similar a:

```
ab
cd
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se declara un array, sino se especifica ningún valor al inicializarlo, todos los campos valen 0.

Por lo tanto los 400 elementos (20x20) de tu matriz tendrán el valor 0.

Ese es justamente el motivo por el cual no ves nada en la pantalla al imprimirlo. 0 (cero) en ascii es equivalente a NULL. Los caracteres imprimibles van desde el 32 hasta el 126 (en la tabla reducida)

Comment: Gracias es lo que quería saber ! ¿Puedo hacer un if == NULL ?

Comment: Si, tranquilamente podes hacer if == NULL o if == 0 que sería exactamente lo mismo

Comment: "*Cuando se declara un array, sino se especifica ningún valor al inicializarlo, todos los campos valen 0.*" **Eso no es cierto** a no ser que el array esté en espacio estático. **Cuando se declara un array sin valor éste no se inicializa** y en consecuencia contiene valores residuales de memoria.

Comment: No imprime nada porque el 0 marca el final de la cadena, no porque sea *no imprimible*. Al hacer `print( condominio )`, la función ve una cadena con 0 caracteres, es decir, una cadena vacía. No imprime 20*20 ceros, sino que directamente no imprime nada.